# Montando um código em C para transformar uma listagem em vetor

Tags: c

gente! Então, eu queria uma ajudinha em um código que eu estava desenvolvendo.
Eu consegui fazer uma base mas em relação ao que eu quero, não estou conseguindo desenvolver o resto.
O que eu quero, é modificar o código de cálculo de preço médio de um galão de tinta de 5 fornecedores e passar a  utilizar vetores p/ armazenar o nome do fornecedor e o seu respectivo preço, exibindo no final o preço médio do produto.

````
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
   // declaracao de variaveis
   float preco1, preco2, preco3, preco4, preco5, media;
   char resposta='S';
   // inicializacao de variaveis
   preco1=0;
   preco2=0;
   preco3=0;
   preco4=0;
   preco5=0;
   media=0;
   // inicio do bloco de repeticao
   while(resposta=='S')
   {
      // limpar a tela
      system("cls");
      // apresentacao do programa
      printf("\t\tPrograma de Calculo de Preco Medio\n\n");
      // entrada de dados
      printf("Entre com o 1. preco: ");
      scanf("%f",&preco1);
      printf("Entre com o 2. preco: ");
      scanf("%f",&preco2);
      printf("Entre com o 3. preco: ");
      scanf("%f",&preco3);
      printf("Entre com o 4. preco: ");
      scanf("%f",&preco4);
      printf("Entre com o 5. preco: ");
      scanf("%f",&preco5);
      // calculo do preco medio
      media = (preco1 + preco2 + preco3 + preco4 + preco5)/5;
      // exibicao do preco medio
      printf("\n\nO preco medio e: %.2f", media);
      // perguntar se quer continuar
      printf("\n\nDeseja continuar (S/N)?");
      scanf("%s",&resposta);
      resposta=toupper(resposta);
   } // fim do bloco de repeticao
}```
````

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

Vai passar os dados para uma tabela onde vai ter o nome do fornecedor e o preço. Então o simples é usar uma tabela. Pode ser algo simples como

```
typedef struct
{
    char  nome[30];
    float preco;
}   Fornecedor;
```

que define um `Fornecedor`.

Pode usar assim

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char  nome[30];
    float preco;
}   Fornecedor;

int main(void)
{
    Fornecedor f[5]; 
    strcpy(f[0].nome, "Willie Nelson"); // primeiro nome
    f[4].preco = 42.42f;

    printf("\
    primeiro fornecedor: %s\n\
    ultimo preco: %6.2f\n", f[0].nome, f[4].preco);
    return 0;
}
```

que mostra

```
    primeiro fornecedor: Willie Nelson
    ultimo preco:  42.42
```

Mas o que quer é algo mais flexível. É a noção de encapsulamento, tão popular na literatura OOP. Imagine uma estrutura Tabela

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned   limite;
    unsigned   qtd;
    Fornecedor f[5];
    char       nome[30];
    float      media;

} Tabela;
```

Agora cada `Tabela` tem um limite, que é o tamanho do vetor. E uma quantidade pra ficar fácil de controlar sem ter variáveis no programa, fora da estrutura. E lá denro está a média e o nome da loja.

Assim pode acrescentar mais campos e o nome Tabela continua sendo o container e não precisa alterar o programa ao mudar um campo por exemplo.

E pode usar assim

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char  nome[30];
    float preco;

}   Fornecedor;


typedef struct
{
    unsigned   limite;
    unsigned   qtd;
    Fornecedor f[5];
    char       nome[30];
    float      media;

}   Tabela;


int main(void)
{
    Tabela tab = {
        .nome = "Filial 42",
        .media = 0.f,
        .limite = 5,
        .qtd = 0
    };

    Fornecedor um;
    strcpy(um.nome, "Willie Nelson");  // primeiro nome
    um.preco = 42.42f;

    tab.f[2] = um;

    int n = 2; // o terceiro fornecedor na tabela
    printf(
        "\
    Loja: %s\n\
    fornecedor #4: %s, preco = %6.2f\n",
        tab.nome, tab.f[n].nome, tab.f[n].preco);
                  
    return 0;
}
```

que mostra

```
    Loja: Filial 42
    fornecedor #4: Willie Nelson, preco =  42.42
```